# "shapes not aligned" in autograd of a tensor norm

Tags: python, tensor, autograd

I would like to use autograd to compute the gradient of the norm of a tensor, as follow:

```
from autograd import grad
import autograd.numpy as np

N = 100; X = np.random.normal(0,1,size=N);
tensor = np.outer(np.outer(X,X),X).reshape(N,N,N);

def cost(X):
    X_t = np.outer(np.outer(X,X),X).reshape(N,N,N);
    return np.linalg.norm(tensor - X_t);
gradient_cost = grad(cost);

X_0 = np.random.normal(0,1,size=N);
gradient_cost(X_0)
```

I also tried different implementation (for instance using my own norm or using different shapes of the tensor) but I always receive the error

> ValueError: shapes (100,100) and (10000,100) not aligned: 100 (dim 1) != 10000
>   (dim 0)

Comment: This is weird, and I don't understand it. The shapes line up fine without autograd. Maybe post this as a github issue to the developers?